# Possible to set Thunderbird to not mark messages as read, by default?

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird

I've just upgraded to 18.04, and the new version of thuderbird seems to no longer have the option to leave messages marked as unread once previewed.  (Unless I'm missing something).

The default behavior is to mark a message as read as soon as it is clicked on.  Previously (in the version that shipped with 16.04), I had the option to make it such that a message was marked as read only once replied-to or manually marked.

Is this feature gone, or is it just buried somewhere?

@mook Here's a screenshot of the "Advanced" menu in the display tab....
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Thunderbird's `Preferences`-window choose `Display` and select the `Advanced`-tab.There you will find the desired option.

[image]

Comment: You sure, mook?

Comment: In the Thunderbird that I am using (version 52.9.1), that option is directly under 'Preferences->Display`  (Seems like an odd place for that setting).

Comment: @generic_user I added a screenshot, you can see that the `Advanced`-tab is selected. My version of Thunderbird is 52.9.1.

Comment: @generic_user Your tabs don't look like tabs, but I can see the title of the tabs in your screenshot. Does it work if you click on the title to switch to the correct tab? (Look for the words `Formatting`, `Tags`, `Advanced` at the top, that should be tabs)

Comment: Whoa.  They totally don't look like tabs with my color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Preview mode will automatically mark messages as read, so to turn this off/on, hit F8 key, in addition to the settings in mook765's image above.