# Delaying or disabling the marking of messages as read when opened in Thunderbird 60+

Tags: thunderbird

There used to be a setting somewhere in Thunderbird to delay the automatic marking of messages as read when opened, or to disable it altogether until the user has manually set a message to read. Many similar answers point to a setting in Display -> Advanced.

But in a recent installation of Thunderbird 60.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 I cannot find this!
The Display panel has been restructured and the tabs that used to be there in earlier versions are no longer!

I could affect the setting manually in the config editor, only if I know the setting's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open **Preferences** and navigate to the **Display** section.
2. Go to the **Advanced** tab.
3. You should find the option under *Reading*:

   [image]
   (screenshot from Thunderbird version 60.2.1)

Comment: Thanks, @pomsky. I found it after careful inspection.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the names and default values I found in my installation:

```
mailnews.mark_message_read.auto;true
mailnews.mark_message_read.delay;false
mailnews.mark_message_read.delay.interval;5
```

[Possible to set Thunderbird to not mark messages as read, by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064216/possible-to-set-thunderbird-to-not-mark-messages-as-read-by-default/1064241#1064241) is a pretty similar question (please read also the comments under the question and answer), it's possible that you have the same problem with your color-scheme.

I can't consider your question as a duplicate because you asked for the names of the configuration items.

Comment: Agreed, doesn't seem to be a duplicate. Also nice pointer on the colour scheme issue : )

Comment: Thanks, mook765. That is indeed useful.
And since this part is what makes my question unique, I will mark this as the accepted answer, even though @pomsky's answer was also useful.